# Invariant sum with diagonalization of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A$ be the $4 \times 4$ matrix on $\mathbb{R}$

$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{array}\right ]$

find matrices $E^{'}_{1}, E^{'}_{2}$ and $E^{'}_{3}$, with $ E^{'}_{1} + E^{'}_{2} + E^{'}_{3} = I$ and $E^{'}_{i}E^{'}_{j} = 0$ if $ i \neq j$.

My try:

i let $A$ define a operator $T: \mathbb{R}^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$. By calculating the characteristic polynomial of $T$ we notice that $T$ is diagonalizable and his eigenvalues are $0, 2$ and $-2$. So i compute the Kernel of the respectives characteristic spaces and i got $dim (Ker T) = 2$, $dim (Ker T-2I) = 1$, and $dim (Ker T+2I )= 1$, then i define three operators with $E_{1}(\mathbb{R}^{4}) = Ker T$, $E_{2}(\mathbb{R}^{4}) = Ker (T-2I)$ and $E_{3}(\mathbb{R}^{4}) = Ker (T+2I)$, so by my calculating the respectives matrices are

$E_{1}^{'} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\end{array}\right ]$    $E_{2}^{'} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\end{array}\right ]$ and $E_{3}^{'} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\end{array}\right ]$ so

$c_{i}$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ and $A = 0E^{'}_{1} + 2E^{'}_{2} + (-2)E^{'}_{3}$, but that matrix $A$ its the diagonal form of $A$ how are the correct way to solve a questions like that?

Comment: From the  problem text, the $E'_i$ seem unrelated to $A$.What is the connection?

Comment: $E^{`}_{i}$ are the matrix representation of the restrictions $E_{i}$(projections) to the $ker(T-c_{i}I)$

Comment: @EduardoSilva - Was that given in the statement of the problem, but you didn't mention it, or are you only describing your attempt at a solution? Mvw's question is about the problem statement itself, where after giving $A$, you make no mention of it in the requirements on the $E_i'$

Comment: i just post the problem and my fail attemp of solution for someone tell how to solve and whats about my solution

Comment: i just wanna know how to get the matrices $E^{'}_{i}$ just this.

Comment: And I just want you to answer my question so I can figure out what the heck you are talking about and so be *able* to help you. But if you can't be bothered to explain the elements you left out of the problem statement, then you are just wasting my time and your own.

Comment: i'm using a theorem that says if $T$ is diagonalizable and its characterist values are $c_{1},...c_{k}$, the exist $E_{1},...E_{k}$ operators such that $T = c_{1}E_{1} + ... + c_{k}E_{k}$, $E_{i}$ are projections and $I = E_{1} + ...E_{k}$

Comment: in my resolution i was trying to compute these projections by the restricion of $T$ in the characterist space,